# Scala Spark : (org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader) Failed to check existence of class org on REPL class server at path

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-notebook

Running basic df.show() post spark notebook installation

I am getting the following error when running scala - spark code on spark-notebook. Any idea when this occurs and how to avoid?

```
[org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader] Failed to check existence of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Object on REPL class server at spark://192.168.10.194:50935/classes
[org.apache.spark.util.Utils] Aborting task
[org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader] Failed to check existence of class org on REPL class server at spark://192.168.10.194:50935/classes
[org.apache.spark.util.Utils] Aborting task
[org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader] Failed to check existence of class
```

Comment: Can you show what you were trying to run as well

Comment: I'm seeing this on a REPL

Answer (score 3):

I installed the spark on local, and when I was using following code it was giving me the same error.

```
spark.read.format("json").load("Downloads/test.json")
```

I think the issue was, it was trying to find some master node and taking some random or default IP. I specified the mode and then provided the IP as `127.0.0.1` and it resolved my issue.

**Solution**

Run the spark using **local** master

```
usr/local/bin/spark-shell --master "local[4]" --conf spark.driver.host=127.0.0.1'
```